# Nominatim Returns a Configuration Error after Assigning a Variable to it

Tags: python, geopy, nominatim

I recently downloaded geopy and tested it out on Jupyter's notebook with the code below.

```
   import geopy
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
    nom=Nominatim(scheme="http")
```

After running this I received the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConfigurationError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-899501bc88f0> in <module>
----> 1 nom=Nominatim(scheme="http")

c:\users\****\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-

packages\geopy\geocoders\nominatim.py in __init__(self, timeout, proxies, domain, scheme, user_agent, ssl_context, adapter_factory)
        103         if (self.domain == _DEFAULT_NOMINATIM_DOMAIN
        104                 and self.headers['User-Agent'] in _REJECTED_USER_AGENTS):
    --> 105             raise ConfigurationError(
        106                 'Using Nominatim with default or sample `user_agent` "%s" is '
        107                 'strongly discouraged, as it violates Nominatim\'s ToS '
    
    ConfigurationError: Using Nominatim with default or sample `user_agent` "geopy/2.0.0" is strongly `discouraged, as it violates Nominatim's ToS https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/ and may possibly cause 403 and 429 HTTP errors. Please specify a custom `user_agent` with `Nominatim(user_agent="my-application")` or by overriding the default `user_agent`: `geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "my-application"`.`
```

I tried the same thing on Pycharm and received the same error. Also tried searching around but couldn't seem to find anything pertaining to my problem.
Would appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please read the ToS, which can be found at the link in the error message. According to the ToS you need to provide your own unique UserAgent. It can be any string, but it has to be created by yourself.

Comment: @KostyaEsmukov Wow, thanks for the swift response. Sorry, can't believe how simple of a mistake it was to solve and it was even in text there... New to programming if it wasn't clear from this question. Thank you.
The exact step I used to solving the problem was writing:
geopy.geocoders.options.default_user_agent = "abc" #Can be any string, as you said.

Comment: `abc` will do, however, keep in mind that if someone else would use the same user agent, you two would share the same quota. That means if that someone would issue a lot of queries, you might start receiving 4xx/5xx errors due to the rate limit. To avoid that you might want to consider using a less generic user agent value.

Comment: Thank you. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: In my case I added ` nom=Nominatim(user_agent="the_name_of_mynotebook")` and it worked perfectly